# Segfault on object destruction on the stack when object containing pointer member?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, heap-memory, destructor, stack-memory

The following scenario seems very perplexing (this isn't a working code, just a much simplified version to illustrate the scenario, you get the idea):

```
class A {
  private:
    B* mb;
  public:
    A(B *b):mb(b) {}
    ~A() {
      if(NULL != mb) { delete mb; }
    }
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   B* b = new B();
   A* a = new A(b);
   delete A; //Everything is fine here
   B b;
   A* a = new A(&b);
   //This will segfault, because b is allocated on the stack?
   delete A; 
   B b;
   //This segfaults as well because when it goes out of scope
   //the program tries to delete b twice?
   A a(&b);
 }
```

If I am understanding this correctly, does it mean you could NEVER allocate such objects like A and B on stack any more when their class definition looks like this? Alternatively, I just simply don't define a destructor for A and then both A and B can be allocated on stack --- but this is probably bad and potentially gives memory leak? (If someday someone else looks at the code and decide to new A).

I thought the major advantage of C++ over Java would be you can avoid new and always deal with objects on stack to speed up, but what about this inflexibility of using an object either on stack or heap, as one like?

What's the deal here in C++? Which of the following two ways should one go then?

1. Define class A as above, and always new both A and B, while later remember to delete A only.
2. Define class A with no destructor, then always create A and B on stack and pass objects around by value (however there are cases I don't want a public copy constructor).

Comment: That code isn't C++.  It doesn't compile.

Comment: This is not complete code, just a simplified example for illustration...

Comment: @Superziyi, that's not helpful. Please post code that can be compiled.

Comment: The Original code is big...however to get a trimmed down version from scratch I have to create new classes that fits the scenario. Aren't the example itself self explanatory though? I don't know there is a SO requirement for every code snippet posted to be compile-able, if that's the case please let me know. Thanks downvoters!

Comment: "Aren't the example itself self explanatory"  **No**.  I'm trying to understand your question, but no.  That code has a lot of errors.

Comment: Sorry I was missing some obvious pointers...and syntax errors, just quickly coded this up...should be clearer now?

Comment: `A(B *b):mb=b {}` is illegal. Please copy and paste the exact code which segfaults.

Comment: Typo...fixed. Thanks for all the downvoting.

Comment: @Superziyi _"Thanks for all the downvoting."_ There were just two (probably valid for your 1st version) downvotes. What are you worrying about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in assuming this segfaults because you're deleting an item that was allocated on the stack. You must only delete items that were allocated with new. Also, it's considered good practice to allocate and free memory within the same layer of code. If you must use object B in your code, it's better to create a copy of B:

```
class A {
  private B* mb;
  public:
    A(B *b) {
      mb = new B(*b); // calls B's copy constructor
    }
    ~A() {
      if(NULL != mb) { delete mb; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Then it means if B does not have a copy constructor then I never really want to use A and B on stack? Is the deal becoming: I either always ensure both objects ever created on stack and don't need to care if I get a destructor (but is it bad design?), or always "new" both objects (and delete A only later) if I new one of them on heap?

Comment: If a class has no custom copy nor move constructors (or assignments) defined, an implicit copy constructor is provided. This copy constructor simply performs a copy of its own members.

Comment: The copy constructor trick rocks! It looks like in this way I can use A and B freely either on stack and heap then! Well I guess the only question left is what is generally a recommended practice. Well I guess if I'm determined to use objects only on stack I wouldn't have declared a pointer member anyway, just an object member...so your solution is probably the way to go if I wish objects can be created either way...

Comment: Actually one more question...when I define A this way, then initialize A and B like: "B b; A a(&b);" Is there an object B ever created on heap?

Comment: No. Memory is allocated from the heap through using 'new type[count]', malloc calls, or operating system APIs.

Comment: Ah sorry I meant, when A a(&b) happens, it internally calls A's constructor which is now "mb = new B(*b)" right? Does this creates something on heap? Or the "new" here is just the copy constructor notion?

Comment: Yes, the new call does allocate B's copy on the heap.

Comment: Ah never mind I understand now, the delete of this B's copy on the heap automatically happens when the A on the stack goes out of scope?

Answer (score 2):

> Which of the following two ways should one go then?

Neither. Use option 3: Don't do this at all.  You are right that an advantage of C++ is that you don't need to `new` and `delete`, but then you wrote a whole bunch of code that uses `new` and `delete`.

What problem are you trying to solve with this `A`? Undoubtedly there is a better way to solve the problem than with `A`.

Comment: Well say in production code I almost never new A. And thus I don't have copy constructor for A either, as I don't want accidental deep copies. Then say in a testing system (or simply unit tests) I want to reuse A for lots of tests. Creating A and setting attributes is nontrivial and I will modularize it. Then it comes the question: how should I pass A around to lots of test functions? Do I start newing A? (so I can pass pointer of heap-allocated-A from function return) Do I start allowing copy constructor on A?

Comment: @Superziyi take out `B *mb` from `A` and all the problems go away. The real issue is why you want `B *mb` in there, and what the relationship is supposed to be between `A` and `B` .

Comment: I see. This make sense. So really there are two distinct cases (echos to my comments on another answer): 1. If I never need to new A and B, then B should just be object member of A; 2. If I do need to new A and B (like A being Tree class and B being Node class but Node is polymorphic so that I cannot hardcode an abstract Node type in function signature and have to return pointers), then stick to newing A and B and maybe using B's copy constructor in A's constructor. The part of the code I am dealing with is existing code that has *mb in A while A and B seem to be always used on stack...

Comment: @Superziyi C++ has smart pointer classes to represent a few common relationships (e.g. shared ownership, single ownership);  you will be able to select one of those that matches the relationship between A and B.   The `shared_ptr` is closest to Java behaviour.   If `B` is a tree node then you *don't* want to call its copy constructor as that would create another node (unless of course you are doing an operation to create a complete copy of the tree).